# how to increase space between legend and chart in chartjs (ng2charts ) using angular

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js, ng2-charts

Hi all I have build a doughnut chart using ng2charts and trying to increase space between legend labels and chart tried many ways it's not working out please let me know if anything I have done wrong

my chart [Check Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-demo-example)

things I have tried
CSS Override

Answer (score 1):

add padding to the legend labels option.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-demo-example-ub4w5v
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#legend-label-configuration

Comment: Padding seems to add spacing to the top of the legend (if the legend has position: 'top', it just generates space between it and the element before). It also has a side effect of creating more space between the labels themselves. This works for my purposes though - just wanted to make that note.